# How to create a formula matching 2 columns names then SUM another adjacent column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

(This is Eve online related but mainly Excel)

I have a spreadsheet with 4 columns.

- Column B has a list of Products (blueprint copy's) (contains duplicates)
- Column C has the amount of runs each copy is capable of (I have more than 1 copy of the same product)
- Column F has the list of the Product name but no duplicates

I would like the adjacent column G to only number the amount of runs from Column B where that number is adjacent to that product.

Example:

[image: Image example]

I am kind of new to Excel.

I already tried `SUMIF()` and `SUMPRODUCT()` - both didn't seem to work the way I wanted.

Comment: What are the problems with the `SUMIF` function? As far as I understand there is enough with `=SUMIF($B$2:$B$17;F2;$C$2:$C$17)`

Comment: That worked thank you very much, would you be able to explain the formula or provide a link to a resource site?